# Does ram speed affect ram usage?

Tags: memory

I worked from home recently and noticed that I only ever hit 10gb/16gb memory usage doing much the same things that I would normally do at work, but with probably quadruple the number of tabs since I had my personal tabs open as well. However at work I commonly hit 99% usage (15+/16).

I'm just curious as to why this could be. My thoughts were maybe the ram speed, since the work one is 1600 while my home one is 3000. Other possibilities are the harddrive vs ssd (but I think this would only matter if I was getting close to the limit right). Also the CPU's are different, i5 6400 vs 3200g.

Comment: Windows 10 - presumably the same release since they both update, but not sure. The apps are mainly VS code and a few other things. But I'm looking more for a general answer rather than why in my specific case. If two computers with different hardware run the same apps would ram speed/ cpu/etc. affect the amount of ram usage.

Comment: RAM usage largely depends on the operating system, as well as programs that are running (including services and background processes). Memory allocation has nothing to do with the speed of its operation. Memory management, on the other hand, is common with programs made with garbage-collected languages (like Java) and with those programs, RAM usage has a correlation with CPU speed and the total RAM capacity.

Comment: @user96931 so what could be a reason that running nearly the same stuff on two different computers results in such a large difference in ram usage?

Comment: Probably there's more going on behind the scenes than you're aware of, like security measures (antivirus, filesystem monitoring), or if it's a shared computer, other sessions. Even a filesystem backup could take up that extra RAM.